# What is a simple algorithm to convert natural numbers to tribit strings?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, numbers

This is a mapping from natural numbers to base-3 strings:

```
 0 =>    0
 1 =>    1
 2 =>    2
 3 =>   00
 4 =>   01
 5 =>   02
 6 =>   10
 7 =>   11
 8 =>   12
 9 =>   20
10 =>   21
11 =>   22
12 =>  000
13 =>  001
14 =>  002
15 =>  010
16 =>  011
17 =>  012
18 =>  020
19 =>  021
20 =>  022
21 =>  100
22 =>  101
23 =>  102
24 =>  110
25 =>  111
26 =>  112
27 =>  120
28 =>  121
29 =>  122
30 =>  200
31 =>  201
32 =>  202
33 =>  210
34 =>  211
35 =>  212
36 =>  220
37 =>  221
38 =>  222
39 => 0000
40 => 0001
...
```

What is the simplest and most efficient functions to perform this mapping, back and forth?

Comment: Shouldn't 0 correspond to the empty string?

Comment: @Bergi nah, the empty string would be NaN, or undefined. I've thought in using it, but then the table doesn't align. Let me know if you have an idea.

Comment: String.toString(n, 3)   produces a string in base 3

Answer (score 1):

It requires some trickery, but can be done using [`Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
function numToBase3(n) {
    var pref = "",
        offset = 0,
        pow = 3;
    while (n >= offset+pow) {
        offset += pow;
        pow *= 3;
        pref += "0";
    }
    return (pref + (n-offset).toString(3)).slice(-1-pref.length);
}
function base3ToNum(s) {
    var offset = 0,
        pow = 3;
    for (var i=1; i<s.length; i++) {
        offset += pow;
        pow *= 3;
    }
    return parseInt(s, 3)+offset;
}
```

(start with `pow = 1` and `i = 0` to map 0 to the empty string)

Comment: You do like `parseInt`, don't you? :) You have my upvote, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, turns out it is quite obvious:

```
function to(base, nat){
    var digits = [];
    while (nat >= 0){
        digits.push(nat % base);
        nat = Math.floor(nat/base)-1;
    };
    return digits;
};
function from(base, digits){
    var nat = digits[digits.length-1];
    for (var i=digits.length-2; i>0; --i)
        nat = (nat + 1) * base + digits[i];
    return nat;
};
```

The tribits are reversed, though. I wonder if there is a way to get the right order without using `reverse` (while pushing to the end of the array).